# How to use an alternate toolset in rpmbuild

Tags: rhel, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am trying to compile & package the latest version of Zeek (5.0.7) for rhel 7 servers.  I get an error saying the "cxx17" is required.  Searching the web, I found that it is contained in devtoolset-7 which I downloaded.  However, I can't find anything telling me what I have to put in the spec file for it to be used.

Comment: You need to add `-std=c++17` to your g++ parameters.

Comment: @doneal24 first, you need to set `CC` (or otherwise inform your build) to use `gcc-7` instead of the default gcc 4.8.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks; but, I still haven't figured out the exact syntax  need to use in the spec file.  I tried ```%global __cc /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/usr/bin/gcc``` and it still sees gcc 4.8

Comment: @Garnet I don't know Zeek at all, but you might need to explicitly `export CC=…`, or supply special options to its configure script, or…; essentially, do the same thing you would need to do outside of a spec file to make it build.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Depends on how the spec file is written. I've seen `g++` explicitly called in the spec. You can also define either `CXX` or `CXXFLAGS` with the option defined. I'm assuming C++ source based on the error message. If it is actually calling `gcc` then the OP will need to use the C flags.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't figure out how to do it in the spec file.  But, I did figure out how to build the package with devtoolset-7.  It has to be enabled before running rpmbuild.

```
$ scl enable devtoolset-7 bash
$ rpmbuild -ba <package>.spec
```